# Get a value from an array of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
ary = [{1=>"January", 2=>"February", 3=>"March"}, {11=>"Oct", 12=>"Nov", 13=>"Dec"}]
```

How can I get the value from a particular hash, based on a key? I would like to do something like:

```
ary[1].select{|h| h[13]}
```

to get the value `"Dec"` from the second hash with the key `13`. The above statement returns the whole second hash, which is not the requirement:

```
{11=>"Oct", 12=>"Nov", 13=>"Dec"}
```

Comment: `ary[1][13] #=> "Dec"`. However, I strongly feel this is an XY problem - what are you actually trying to achieve here? Why are you using this data structure?

Comment: If you want the value from key, why're you making it array of hashes and not just merging the hashes and accessing via key. Something like, `a.merge(b)[13] #=> "Dec"`.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want: `b = {10 => "Oct", 11 => "Nov", 12 => "Dec"}`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The select statement will return all the hashes with the key 13.

If you already know which hash has the key then the below code will give u the answer.

```
ary[1][13]
```

However if you are not sure which of your hashes in the array has the value, then you could do the following:

```
values = ary.map{|h| h[13]}.compact
```

Values will have the value of key 13 from all the hashes which has the key 13.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two hashes in one and then query the keys of the merged hash.

```
c = a.merge(b)
  => {1=>"January", 2=>"February", 3=>"March", 11=>"Oct", 12=>"Nov", 13=>"Dec"}
```

And then you can do something like:

```
c[1]
  => "January"
```

---

Otherwise, if you want to keep the format as an array of different hashes you can just get the value you want this way:

```
ary[1][12]
  => "Nov"
```

But that way you have to always know in which hash inside the array is the element you want, which seems a bit confusing because you could just use different hashes instead of an array of hashes and having to remember each hash's position inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make a single hash and then return the value of hash by key.

Make single hash from array with merging elements.

- Method 1

  `hash = ary.reduce({}, :merge)`
- Method 2

  `hash = ary.inject(:merge)`

Then return the value by key.

`hash[13]`